# Fastest way to find all-pair shortest paths in a undirected cycle

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have and undirected graph that is in itself a simple cycle like this

```
a---b---c
|       |       
d---e---f
```

Which is the fastest way to compute all-pair shortest paths knowing this condition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one pass starting from `A` traverse the graph clockwise, and for every node compute the distance from `A`. Let's say the distance to the node `X` is `a[X]`. This way for any pair `(X, Y)` of nodes the distance will be:

```
min(abs(aX - aY), total - abs(aY - aX))
```

Where `total` is the sum of all the edges weights.

In your case `a[B]` (I will use upper case for nodes) would be 1, `a[C]` would be 2, `a[D]` would be 3 etc and the total would be 6. Then if you want to compute the distance between b and f, it would be

```
min(abs(aB - aF), total - abs(aB - aF)) = 
min(abs( 1 -  3),     6 - abs( 1 -  3)) = 
min(           2,                    4) =
2
```

Comment: i don't follow it , can you expand a little more your response.